# Data transfer betweeen two nfc capable devices without using android beam

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I am developing an app with which I transfer a vcard between two nfc capable devices. I am able to do it if both the devices have android beam. I want to know if it is possible to transfer information from an ICS device(Having android beam) to a gingerbread device(which does not have android beam)...Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Android supports two modes for operating with NFC:

P2P -> Android Beam //
Tag Reader -> "Advanced NFC Framework"

If i'm not wrong, Android Beak is supported in Gingerbread too, so you shoudn't have to face any problem exchanging data between two Android NFC devices with Beam.

The second way, is only for making operations with Tags. Android does not support card emulation officially so this is not an option for you.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html

Look at EnableForegroundDispatch method: since API Level 10 = Gingerbread

Comment: The only diff between Gingerbread and ICS is that Ginger implements NPP protocol, and ICS implements both NPP and SNEP protocols (because of retrocompatibilty)

Check this paragraph:

The NFC device that is receiving the beamed data must support the com.android.npp NDEF push protocol or NFC Forum's SNEP (Simple NDEF Exchange Protocol). The com.android.npp protocol is required for devices on API level 9 (Android 2.3) to API level 13 (Android 3.2). com.android.npp and SNEP are both required on API level 14 (Android 4.0) and later.

Comment: got it ... I am now able to transfer data from a gingerbread device to an ics device because enableForegroundNdefPush is working on gingerbread devices but not on ics devices...I want to know how to implement p2p data transfer from ics to gingerbread

Comment: Its the same, ICS supports both modes. EnableForegroundNDefPush works on both versions, thats what i'm trying to say. Just open Chrome and navigate Google.com on ICS device, and then put the Gingerbread device near the first, you will see that ICS device will prompt you to share the content, thats BEAM

Comment: you mean to say that after the beam ui shows up in ics, it will use enableForegroundNdefMessage to transfer data to gingerbread device instead of setBeamPushUris